# phpmailer sending to CC works fine, but CC not being displayed in mail (like BCC) when in SMTP mode

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

PHPmailer Version: 2.0.4

when running the following lines

```
$Mail = new PHPMailer();
$Mail->IsSMTP();
$Mail->AddAddress("first@mail.com");
$Mail->AddCC("second@mail.com");
... set some body, set host, set sender info, and so on
$Mail->send();
```

both first and second would get the mail, but the second address does not appear on the mail as a CC, just like it was BCCed instead of CCed.

when commenting out the IsSMTP() => using default 'mail' mode, the CC is being displayed as expected.

tried to google this effect, but seems like i'm the only person on the planet having experienced this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> address does not appear on the mail

Your question is barely answearable due to lack of data like raw headers of sent mails. I'd ask for this in the comment but I think it's pointless in your case because...

> PHPmailer Version: 2.0.4

I hardly see version 2.0.4 in [PHPMailer's changelog](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/changelog.md), but assuming it has been released somewhere between release of `2.0.0 rc2` and `2.1.0 beta1` it still means you are using code released around *Dec 2007*

**Upgrade for god's sake!**

Comment: thnx for hint. I actually did upgrade last month, but obviously i caught an historic url...
Works all fine with the newest version now !

Answer (score -1):

might have found the solution already:

PHPMailer Class, function CreateHeader(), line 890

original code:

if((($this->Mailer == 'sendmail') || ($this->Mailer == 'mail')) && (count($this->cc) > 0)) {
  $result .= $this->AddrAppend('Cc', $this->cc);
}

my new fixed code:

if((($this->Mailer == 'sendmail') || ($this->Mailer == 'mail') || ($this->Mailer == 'smtp')) && (count($this->cc) > 0)) {
  $result .= $this->AddrAppend('Cc', $this->cc);
}

originally the AddrAppend() function is only called when mode is set to 'sendmail' or 'mail', but it need also to be called for 'smtp' mode

no idea whether this situation was intented by the PHPmailer staff or it's just a bug, which needs to be fixed.

Comment: your updating code that has probably already been fixed, and are not using the formatting correctly here ... down vote ... this code is also hosted on github where you can submit `issues` and `pull requests` to their latest code